# Mongodb search improvement about tags

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, key-value

Tried mongodb with 8 GB js (split and loaded),  when doing aggregate:

`$result = $ele->aggregate([{ '$match' => { tag => { '$all' => \@tags } } }]);`

It needs longer than 30s.

Is there any kind of methods to transform data for fast retrieving.

the stats on collection is this:

```
    { 
            "ns" : "sentence.element",
            "count" : 30698264,
            "size" : 12568211328,
            "avgObjSize" : 409,
            "storageSize" : 13598789584,
            "numExtents" : 27,
            "nindexes" : 2,
            "lastExtentSize" : 2146426864,
            "paddingFactor" : 1,
            "systemFlags" : 1,
            "userFlags" : 1,
            "totalIndexSize" : 8616318480,
            "indexSizes" : {
                    "_id_" : 996629872,
                    "tag_1" : 7619688608
            },
            "ok" : 1
    }
```

the document is like this:

```
    {
       name:20,
       tag:['world','a','but','critical','in','hello'],
       value:'but hello world plays a critical role in'
     }
```

I want to search the tag using 'but' 'hello' 'critical' to get the value.
the machine has 64G memory

Comment: Asking for recommendations for tools or products is "off-topic". See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). But really, did you even index the "tag" field? How much memory is in the machine you are using? How many values are you asking to match in that array? How many values are stored in the arrays? Right now you are just blaming the product without understanding that you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I didn't index the tag field...Now it is very fast :-)  (indexed the tag).  I didn't mean to blame it.  Thank you Neil Lunn

Comment: when I used it a lot, I found it is fast some times, but time out(30s) frequently. I have to search it again, and in the 2nd search ,it become fast, but I may search it again and again for 3 or 4 times....